# Returning mutable Map reference in Rust

Tags: rust, reference, mutable, ownership

My goal is to add some dev dependencies to `Cargo.toml` programatically.

I am using the `toml` crate (`toml = { version = "0.5.8", features = ["preserve_order"] }`).

Here is the part of code where I am trying to get the Map of dev dependencies or create a new Map when dev deps are not defined.

```
let mut dev_deps = cargo_toml_content
    .get_mut("dev-dependencies")
    .and_then(Value::as_table_mut)
    .unwrap_or_else(|| ???);
```

The `Value::as_table_mut` part of code returns `Option<&mut Table>` where `Table` is `Map<String, Value>`. If the function doesnt return anything, I would like to initialize a new Map in `unwrap_or_else` block and return it.

I am able to return a new Map / Table but I dont know how to return a mutable reference of the Map. I am struggling with the ownerhip things like `returns a reference to data owned by the current function` when I use something like this:

```
...
.unwrap_or_else(|| {
    let mut table = Table::default();
    &mut table
});
```

So what (and how) should I do to correctly return the mutable reference of Table? Or is there a better solution on how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to do with the resulting table?

Comment: I would like to find or add (missing) dev dependencies there and then write the result to the `Cargo.toml`

Something like this: `dev_deps.entry(name).or_insert(value);`

Comment: What's the type of `cargo_toml_content`? Is it a `toml::value::Table` or `toml::Value`?

Comment: The type of `cargo_toml_content` is `toml::Value`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the map outside of the callback:

```rust
let mut empty = Table::default();
let mut dev_deps = cargo_toml_content
    .get_mut("dev-dependencies")
    .and_then(Value::as_table_mut)
    .unwrap_or(&mut empty);
```

But it's better to just `match`.

If you want to re-insert the map at the end anyway, it will be better to put it there from the beginning.

Comment: This might be a bit misleading. as this won't insert into `cargo_toml_content`, but only into the temporary `Option` returned by `as_table_mut`